# Awk or shell script for executing following program

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, grep

```
mansa, amit, janani ,[rakesh]
aruna,mahesh,,prathiksha
```

This is my input.
I need a shell script or a awk command that gives me output in following manner

```
mansa
amit
janani 
rakesh
aruna
mahesh
prathiksha
```

The script should remove all ,'s brackets.

I tried this

```
awk -F "\[\][,]+" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}'
```

but its printing one extra line after each record.

Answer (score 5):

Easier with `grep`:

```
$ grep -o '[a-z]\+' file
mansa
amit
janani
rakesh
aruna
mahesh
prathiksha
```

Comment: Would it be also ok `grep -o '[a-z]\*' file`?

Comment: @fedorqui the quantifier `+` is part of the extended regexp class so I needs to be escaped *(or use the `-E` option, or `egrep`)* however `*` is standard regexp so doesn't need escaping so you would need to do `grep '[a-z]*' file` the differences is `+` means one or more whilst `*` means zero or more both give the same results in this case but `*` and `+` are definitely not interchangeable.

Comment: Or rather `\+` is a GNU extension to basic regular expressions (BRE).

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be `tr`:

```
tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '[\n*]' < file
```

---

Although it would create empty lines if there is leading whitespace, which could then be filtered out:

```
tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '[\n*]' < file | awk NF
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to remove square brackets and split the items from within comma delimeters, you could use the following:

```
perl -pe 's/,+/,/g ; s/[\[\]]//g ; s/\s*,\s*/\n/g' foo.txt
```

The reason I recommend this approach is in the event that your named values have numbers in them or other non-alpha characters you may want to preserve.

The perl expression above contains 3 regular expressions.  First part reduces multiple commas into one (to avoid empty values between commas.  The second part removes the square braces.  The third part splits values by replacing commas (with whitespace on either left or right) with newlines.

Output would be as follows:

```
mansa
amit
janani
rakesh
aruna
mahesh
prathiksha
```